# Receive WM_COPYDATA struct in WPF or Console C# app

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, console, interprocess

I am writing a C# application that needs to communicate with another application written in native C. So far I have figured out how to send messages from my C# app to the C app with the User32.dll SendMessage. However I am unable to figure out how to get the C# app to RECEIVE messages from the C app.

I have seen WinForms examples of overriding the WndProc method, but there is no WndProc method to override in a WPF or Console application. Surely it's possible to do in a Console application at least. Right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in WPF using [HwndSource.AddHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.addhook.aspx):

```
private HwndSource hwndSource;
void MyWindowClass_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
}
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    // Process your windows proc message here          
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no real equivelent for a Console Application.  Windows messages, by definition, are sent and received by a window handle (HWND), so they really are meant to be used with GUI applications.

There are many other, less odd, means of doing [inter-process communication on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx), however.  I personally like using pipes - setting up named pipes works very well in both native and managed code, and is very efficient for communicating between the two programs.